# MySQL trigger after insert and after update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables with one named `att` as follows

```
CREATE TABLE att (
  SID varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  CID varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  Date date NOT NULL,
  H1 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  H2 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  H3 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  H4 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  H5 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  H6 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  H7 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  H8 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  H9 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  H10 varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  INDEX (SID, CID)
);
```

The other table is `per` with following fields:
SID CID Per

How do I write a trigger for the following:
If an update occurs in any of the fields from h1-h0 on `att` table then
update the `per` column in the `per` table with the following values:
((total no of 1s - total no of 0s)/(total no of 1s + total no of 0s))/100

Thanks in advance
i Developed a Trigger,but it not working,its saying error in line 11,can you say what is the problem??

```
create TRIGGER `att_up` AFTER UPDATE ON `attentance`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE Zeros INT;
  DECLARE Ones INT;
  DECLARE total INT;
  DECLARE atted FLOAT;
  SELECT SUM(8-(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8)) 
      INTO Zeros FROM attentance 
      WHERE StudID=NEW.StudID;
  SELECT SUM(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8) 
      INTO Ones FROM attentance 
      WHERE StudID=NEW.StudID;
  SELECT SUM(8-(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8))+ SUM(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8) 
      INTO total FROM attentance 
      WHERE StudID=NEW.StudID;
  set atted=((ZEROS-Ones)/total)/100;
  INSERT into per(per) values (atted);
END$$
```

Comment: if possible can you paste the table schema or else you can refer this link for how to create triggers http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: here it is....is this enough??can you help me to create one trigger??

Comment: I think `INSERT INTO per SET per=atted; ` is not right. INSERT SYNTAX is `INSERT INTO table(field1, field2...) VALUES(value1,value2...)`

Comment: @Jose: my mYsql Showing the error in line 3:(

Comment: this is the error i am getting '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3 '

Comment: @Jose : Done, but same error :(

Comment: I changed the query, this is my new query for trigger

Comment: At the beginning of your query put DELIMITER $$

Comment: @Jose : if you got a working query then can u please add that in the Answer and post??

Comment: @Alex: What are the real world attributes you're modeling in the tables? Are there any unique indices (on e.g. "SID" or "SID, CID") on either table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you change the delimiter before defining the trigger. Also make sure you're using the same table and column names when you create the table and the trigger (you're using `att` and `attendance`, and `SID` and `StudID`, in your examples).

As it is, the trigger definition caused no error when I tested it in MySQL 5.1.55 after setting the delimiter.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `att_up` 
  AFTER UPDATE ON `attendance`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE Zeros INT;
  DECLARE Ones INT;
  DECLARE total INT;
  DECLARE attend FLOAT;
  SELECT SUM(8-(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8)), 
         SUM(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8),
         SUM(8-(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8)) + SUM(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8)
    INTO Zeros, Ones, Total FROM attendance 
    WHERE SID=NEW.SID;
  SET attend=((Zeros-Ones)/total)/100;
  INSERT INTO per (SID, CID, per) values (NEW.SID, NEW.CID, attend)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE per=attend;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Can u send me a trigger code for that?? as i am new in trigger coding in mysql, the above code is developed through seeing some tutorials and so on

Comment: outis is right. The delimiter should be $$ (because you copy an example and you didn't remove it =P) Jaja

Comment: @Jose,@outis : can you guys show me an example, i am getting super confuse...what should i do and where??

Answer (score -1):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `att_up` AFTER UPDATE ON `attentance`
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

SET @zeros = 0;
SET @ones = 0;
SET @total = 0;
SET @atted = 0;


(SELECT (8-SUM(h1)+SUM(h2)+SUM(h3)+SUM(h4)+SUM(h5)+SUM(h6)+SUM(h7)+SUM(h8)) INTO @zeros FROM attentance WHERE StudID=NEW.StudID);
(SELECT SUM(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8) INTO @ones FROM attentance WHERE StudID=NEW.StudID);
(SELECT (SUM(8-(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8))+ SUM(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5+h6+h7+h8)) INTO @total FROM attentance WHERE StudID=NEW.StudID);

SELECT (((@zeros-@ones)/@total)/100) INTO @atted FROM (SELECT 1) AS x;

END$$
```

Comment: i got this error :( #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; SET @ones; SET @total; SET @atted; @zeros = (SELECT SUM(8-(h1+h2+h3+h4+h' at line 3

Comment: Test it now. I change the first select because i didn't know SUM can accept expressions