# A calculated field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, calculated-field

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL trigger after insert and after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201497/mysql-trigger-after-insert-and-after-update)

I have a table with for example:
Type | Platform | Name | Version | FullName

I want to have FullName update with "Type.Platform.Name.Version" when there is an insert or update.

I thought that CONCAT_WS('.', Type,Platform,Name,Version) would provide the data I want but how do I get it into the FullName field?

I looked at triggers but they won't work to update the same table as the data lives in.
I didn't see a way to automate a store procedure, but maybe I'm not fulling understanding them.

Perhaps a table with only the FullName field that could be triggered?  Any insight appreciated!

Comment: have you considered creating a view?

Comment: Why do you believe triggers will not work for you?

Comment: @JW, yes it seems to be a duplicate.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

You can do the BEFORE INSERT & BEFORE UPDATE Triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER fullname_update BEFORE UPDATE ON table
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.fullname = CONCAT_WS('.', NEW.type, NEW.platform, NEW.name, NEW.version);
  END;
```

You can do the same for BEFORE INSERT trigger. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not stuck on a particular version of MySQL, you may want to consider [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/), which has support for "[virtual columns](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/virtual-columns/)." This would solve the problem you're having.

Note that MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, so you'll stil have all standard MySQL functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is [MySQL views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html).

You have a table that contains the actual data, and an entity that is called "view", that you can use as a regular table - make requests from it, make updates, etc.
I used it numerous times exactly for the same purpose as you ask, you should explore them.

Of course, there are limitations to usages, but according to your question it would fit your needs.